# AngularJS & One way binding

Tags: angularjs

How do you implement one-way binding? Please provide some explanation on why and when you would use one-way binding.

I'm new to AngularJS.

Comment: angular is realtime two way data binding framework, you can bind your data in `ng-bind` or in `{{ expression }}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does data binding work in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/how-does-data-binding-work-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

> Please provide some explanation on why and when you would use one-way binding.

Possible Reasons:

1. You want to speed up your app.
2. You want your Angular 1 to have an easier upgrade path to Angular 2
3. You have a value that you want to pass to several children, but when the children change the value, you don't want the other children to sync this change.

> How do you implement one-way binding?

Before Angular 1.5 you can make a make a deep copy of your object with `angular.copy` once you pass it in, so e.g. `myVal = angular.copy(myVal)`. After Angular 1.5, you can use `<` in your bindings, which would then look like that:

```
bindings: {
  myVal: "<"
}
```

However, note that if myVal is an object, you'll still have to do the deep copy using `angular.copy`, the "<" only works for non-object values. See the following [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/3M3PhyfQr64ZZRnaP10G?p=preview) to see what I mean.